# Nano is putting random B's everywhere

Tags: ubuntu, nano

I've got a really weird issue with `nano`.

[image]

It's putting B's all over any file I open. These aren't saved to the file, or in the file normal, there just displayed inside of nano.

Anyone got any idea what on earth is going on?

The set up is, I'm running Windows 8.1, and using a program called Boot2Docker, to run Docker images, and this image is Ubuntu. If you want any more info, just let me know.

Comment: What are your terminal's settings?

Comment: Do you mean the CMD wrapper settings, or the terminal inside of Boot2Docker?

Comment: Did you ever work out what was doing this? I'm having the same issue in Windows 10 Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

Comment: Nope, never found a solution for it :(

Comment: Did you get a solution to this issue? it's annoying I keep getting the same random B's and sometimes A's